# Java Web Start wont download updated application when run

Tags: java, versioning, jnlp, java-web-start

I've read that JWS checks the jnlp or the jar file on the server for a timestamp change to detect if there are updated files, but my application updates don't download automatically when I run an application a second time.

If i javaws -uninstall, then launch the app again, it works fine so I know the files on the server are updated. I also checked the time stamps on the FTP, and they are updated when new files are uploaded, so I don't think thats the issue either.

Can anybody help? It'd be very greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148454/java-webstart-intermittant-jar-not-updating

Comment: Does your JNLP have a codebase attribute set?

Comment: Yes, I have the codebase attribute set to the url of the folder it's hosted in, and the href set to the jnlp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your program to update itself, your JNLP file should include the following:

```
 <update check="always"/>
```

You can place this after the information tag, not inside of it.

Comment: I haven't worked on this project for almost a year, so I have no way to test if this answer is correct for my specific case, but I'll mark it as an answer because I'm sure this may solve it for others!